# Flex very strange casting error

Tags: java, apache-flex, blazeds

I'm going mad with an error non error on my web-app Flex 3.6 based (using BlazeDS). I try to describe my issue: I have a java class:

```
public class User {...}
```

and the binding one in .as:

```
[Bindable]
[RemoteClass(alias="it.dto.User")]
public class User {...}
```

I also have a DataManager.as to do the Async call like this:

```
public function getUser():void {
    var token:AsyncToken = _service.getUser();
    token.addResponder(new AsyncResponder(userOnResult,userOnFault));
}
private function userOnFault(event:FaultEvent,token:Object):void {
    var _fail:String = "Error";
}
private function socOnResult(event:ResultEvent,token:Object):void {
    _resUser = event.result as ArrayCollection;
    dispatchEvent(new MyEvent("USER_EVENT",_resUser));
}
```

Now I implemented the following code in two different .as file (different package), which refers to two different .mxml:

```
var data:DataManager = new DataManager;
....
data.addEventListener("USER_EVENT",userResult);
....
data.getUser();
....
private function userResult(dataEvent:MyEvent):void {
    var user:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection;
    user = dataEvent.result as ArrayCollection;
    for (var i:int = 0;i<user.length; i++) {
        var u:User = new User;
        u = (User)(user.getItemAt(i));
    }
    _dm.removeEventListener("USER_EVENT",userResult);
}
```

The drama is that in the first .as it works perfectly, and in the second .as give me a Error of coercion failed. In the second file seems how it can't recognize the User class.
Do you have any idea?? I'm going mad!!
Thank you

@Stacktrace error:

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert   appcode.dto::SocietaDTO@b4dbfc1 to appcode.dto.SocietaDTO.
at modules::ReportIspezioni/onSocResult()[D:\workspace\maga\aga\flex_src\modules\ReportIspezioni_src.as:80]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at appcode.dao::DataManager/socOnResult()[D:\workspace\maga\aga\flex_src\appcode\dao\DataManager.as:180]
at mx.rpc::AsyncResponder/result()[C:\autobuild\3.x\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AsyncResponder.as:82]
at mx.rpc::AsyncToken/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::applyResult()[C:\autobuild\3.x\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AsyncToken.as:199]
at mx.rpc.events::ResultEvent/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::callTokenResponders()[C:\autobuild\3.x\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\events\ResultEvent.as:172]
at mx.rpc::AbstractOperation/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::dispatchRpcEvent()[C:\autobuild\3.x\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AbstractOperation.as:199]
at mx.rpc::AbstractInvoker/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::resultHandler()[C:\autobuild\3.x\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AbstractInvoker.as:263]
at mx.rpc::Responder/result()[C:\autobuild\3.x\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\Responder.as:46]
at mx.rpc::AsyncRequest/acknowledge()[C:\autobuild\3.x\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AsyncRequest.as:74]
at NetConnectionMessageResponder/resultHandler()[C:\autobuild\3.x\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\messaging\channels\NetConnectionChannel.as:524]
at mx.messaging::MessageResponder/result()[C:\autobuild\3.x\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\messaging\MessageResponder.as:199]
```

Obviusly the User class written above is just for example, to understand the code logic. The real class is a DTO calls SocietaDTO.
N.B: The code works perfectly in another module of my project.. I don't understand why here it doesn't work.

Thanks a lot

Comment: what is the actual error and stacktrace

Comment: @junior_developer, please post an answer to your question if you've figured this out rather than editing the answer in to the question body.

Comment: Make sure you have cleared the browser cache before searching the reason for unexpected behavior. Especially if you are using modules there could be old .swf files in the cache which make your application behave strange.

Answer (score 0):

I never save browser cache when developing.. Anyway I solve the Issue by adding this:

```
registerClassAlias("it.mec.dto.SocietaDTO", SocietaDTO);
```

In the class were exception launch.

Thanks anyway